# Maven 3 - Use different dependencies in test and compile

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a project with a dependency on Spring version 3. I've written integration tests that depend on features in Spring 4. How do I run my tests with Spring 4 (integration tests only would be the best, but running unit tests in Spring 4 would be acceptable) but keep my compile dependency on 3?

I've already considered a module for integration tests. It's less than ideal, so I'm looking for solutions that do not require modules.

Comment: To be honest...sounds strange if your code depends on Spring version 3 whereas your IT's depends on Spring 4...I would change the code and than you have the same version?....Apart from that you could have different dependencies within a separate integration test module...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more consideration I think this is a perfect candidate for modules. I created one module for my code and unit tests and a separate Spring 4 dependent module for my IT's